# Why won't Firefox parse this XSLT?

Tags: xml, firefox, xslt

I've recently been playing around with XML formatting and XLST files, because it seems like the most direct solution to a UI problem I've been wrestling with involving users accessing the central data differently.  In my experimentation I've created a really nice formatting sheet that looks great... in Internet Explorer.  When I test it in Firefox, I consistently get the same error message:

"Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed."

I've tried paring the stylesheet down to a very basic document and still experience the same problem. I've been checking tutorials and other webforums and mimic'ing examples, but I can't seem to find anything that is explicitly applicable.

Here's my test XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="fox.xslt"?>
<article>
   <title>Making Excellent Pasta Sauce</title>
   <synopsis>A simple recipe for an amazing sauce, with tips on getting that extra flavor.</synopsis>
   <content>Here is my content.</content>
   <tags>
      <tag>sauce</tag>
      <tag>recipes</tag>
   </tags>
</article>
```

And then, here's my XSLT file (named, as you might tell from the example block above, "fox.xslt".

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
   <xsl:for-each select="article">
      TITLE: <xsl:value-of select="title"/> <BR/>
      SYNOPSIS: <xsl:value-of select="synopsis"/> <BR/><BR/>
   </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I suspect that it may have something to do with 
    `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">` because I've seen a few different things done with this in examples, I've tried a few of the different values here and haven't seem to hit on one that works with this example.

I'm sure it's probably a basic problem, I just have been flummoxed at tracking down.  Hopefully someone can lead me to the "forehead smacking moment".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace your stylesheet element with this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
```

You may also want to add this:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

Comment: I should say it works with `version="1.0"` (or 1.1) too. The main issue is probably the `xsl` namespace.

Comment: The problem **is** the XSLT namespace. But your answer missed explanation. That namespace URI `http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl` was used by earlier M$ productos implementing an old XSLT Working Draft. Later this was deprecated. None complain XSLT processor up today allows this namespace.

Comment: @Alejandro, yes indeed, but I've just tested on Firefox 3.6 and if the `version` attribute is missing, it doesn't work either (so both issues need to be fixed).

Answer (score 2):

I find it most useful to use a separate tool to find the problems that FireFox (et al) will not report.  Install and use, say, the **xsltproc** command, which gives much more helpful results.

For example, I encountered a file where Firefox's only response was (take your pick):  "Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed" or, with version=1.1 in the stylesheet, " the equally useless "Parsing an XSLT expression failed."

So, I went to the command-line and entered, *say* ..."xsltproc bah.xsl humbug.xml" then, presto, there it was:

```
error
xsltCompileStepPattern : ']' expected
compilation error: file bah.xsl line 157 element template
xsltCompilePattern : failed to compile 'ATOM[@STATE='GAS''
```

I therefore routinely run all of my XML and XSL files through *xsltproc* or its equivalent such that they "run clean" before feeding it to my friendly neighborhood browser.  I have not yet found *any* browser that "graciously and informatively" handles an XSLT issue.

In addition, I find it quite-frankly *easier* to look at the command output (which is HTML), say by piping it to the *less* or *more* commands for pagination, than to try looking at it in a browser, until I know that I am very close to what I am looking for.  If I'm trying to find a problem in the generated (say) HTML output, I really don't want to look at it "as HTML" at first.  If the XSL transforms are "spewing nonsense" (as, of course, they *do* at first, at least for me), a browser's attempts to turn it into something beautiful just gets in the way of finding the bugs in the stylesheet.